# Why there are less number of nodes in the saved file than that in the original graph?

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to save a graph as edge list using network as follows:

```
nx.write_edgelist(G, 'test_edges.csv', delimiter= ' ,',data=False)
```

And then i read it back as follows:

```
G11=nx.read_edgelist('test_edges.csv',create_using=nx.Graph(), nodetype=int,delimiter= ' ,')
```

but when I print number of nodes i get different results:

```
print(G.number_of_nodes())6606

print(G11.number_of_nodes())1790
```

what's wrong? and what should I do? Thank you for your support

Comment: The question is not clear. provide more code.

Comment: I am trying to read a saved networkx graph, but i am getting different number of nodes  from the original graph @user3134614

Comment: It is very difficult to answer your question without seeing any of your data which produces your problem. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help you.